# Python indexing integer and float

Tags: python, list, indexing, floating-point, int

I have a doubt as suppose i have a list mixed list of elements as

```
Pylist = [1,2,3,'a','b','c',2.0,2.2]
```

now if i retrieve the index value of 1 and 6 it provides me as

```
>>> Pylist[1]
2
>>> Pylist[6]
2.0
```

and if i check the type they return int and float respectively but when i use **index** method on it, will return me the same index position after which there type is different, index place and value also, can anyone explain

```
>>> Pylist.index(2)
1
>>> Pylist.index(2.0)
1
>>>
```

???

Answer (score 2):

It's because `2 == 2.0` is `True` and [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method finds first value that meets this condition, searching throught the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get index `2.0` value you can use `isinstance(Pylist[i], float)`:

```
[i for i,k in enumerate(Pylist) if isinstance(Pylist[i], float) and Pylist[i] == 2.0] # [6]
```

Comment: thanks it provides a different prospective to look at it, very well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to return the index of each `2`/`2.0`:

```py
for i in set(Pylist):
    if Pylist.count(i) > 1:
        print(" ".join([str(index) for index, value in enumerate(Pylist) if value == el]))
```